# Android Mail Reading With Javamail API

Tags: android, api, object, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm taking emails from my Inbox folder with javamail api for my Android Application,

Is is possible to "just" have mail body with "content.toString()" ? If it's possible ,how can i view the mail body part by using adapters ? I tried SimpleAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter but content is a type of Object, doesn't fit with the adapters.

What do you offer ?

Thanks.

```
private Message message;
private Object content;

message = inboxReader.inbox.getMessage(Integer.parseInt(_bundle.getString("RowId").toString()));
content = message.getContent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody

Comment: yes it is, but i would like to know how can i show the body part in an android application.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try it

```
private static String getMailContent(Multipart multipart) throws IOException, MessagingException{
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        String disposition = bodyPart.getDisposition();
        if (disposition != null && (disposition.equals(BodyPart.ATTACHMENT))) {
                // ................................
        } else {
            content.append(bodyPart.getContent());
        }
    }
    return content.toString();
}
```